# Calculate in closed form: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sin x}}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I did the replacement, $u = \sqrt{2\sin x}$, but I did not succeed. $u = \sqrt{2\sin x}$. I found,
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan(x)\cot(x)\,dx, \quad \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin x)\,dx
$$
But the techniques used in these integrals did not help much.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This leads to a hypergeometric function $$\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(9 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{1}{4}\right
   )-\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{1}{4}\right
   )}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)}\right)}{9 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$

Comment: It was proposed in a mathematical discussion group. The author says that the solution involves the Catalan constant.

Comment: An initial step could be the use of $$\arctan(1/x)=\frac\pi2-\arctan x$$ So we have that $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan\left[\frac1{\sqrt{2\sin x}}\right]dx=\frac{\pi^2}4-\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sqrt{2\sin x})dx$$